# How to take the value from this object and form a comma separated string with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

I have an object as follows,

```
{"Ticket-1.pdf":"8e6e8255-a6e9-4626-9606-4cd255055f71.pdf","Ticket-2.pdf":"106c3613-d976-4331-ab0c-d581576e7ca1.pdf"}
```

i need the output as,

```
8e6e8255-a6e9-4626-9606-4cd255055f71,106c3613-d976-4331-ab0c-d581576e7ca1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object.values()

```
const data = {"Ticket-1.pdf":"8e6e8255-a6e9-4626-9606-4cd255055f71.pdf","Ticket-2.pdf":"106c3613-d976-4331-ab0c-d581576e7ca1.pdf"};
const values = Object.values(data).map(x => x.substr(0, x.length - 4));
const commaJoinedValues = values.join(',');
console.log(commaJoinedValues);
```

Comment: i need comma separated string

Comment: sorry again, i dont need the .pdf extension as mentioned in the question

Comment: ah sorry, heh, fixed again :)

Comment: it works in javascript but not with typescript, any idea?

Comment: Sorry no.  You should tag your post with typescript tag and perhaps add it to the title and the question body.  You posted your question in [javascript].

Comment: i will mark this as answer, and post a new question